# How to update a special package only?

Tags: package, julia

When run `Pkg.update()`, all package will be updated if it is not pinned or dirty.
But it is possible to update a special package(such as FackCheck)?
I have taken a little look on the Julia source code, but haven't fond the direct solution.
I know I can pin all packages and when want to update someone, just unpin the package then run `Pkg.update()`, but I think it is not a good way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also navigate to the package directory and type `git checkout master && git pull`. You can say `Pkg.free("SomePackage")` when you want to go back to having the package manager take charge of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which package version you want to use you can do something along these lines.

```
Pkg.rm("FactCheck")
Pkg.add("FactCheck", v"0.1.1")
```

But that will also fix FactCheck at that version so a Pkg.update() will ignore it.

The slightly more crude and manual variant would be:

- Goto https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl/
- Search the Pacakge you want and the latest version
- In the case of Factcheck that would be https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl/tree/metadata-v2/FactCheck/versions/0.1.2
- Now copy the value in sha1 file
- `cd ~/.julia/v0.3/FactCheck`
- `git checkout $sha1 .`

But in this case you might be missing potential requirements.

So assuming that what you wan is not a specific version but the `master` branch for the bleeding edge version you can simply do.

```
Pkg.rm("FactCheck")
Pkg.clone("FactCheck")
```

But now you are working with a potential unstable version.

So in the end the question is what specific use case do you have that warrants only updating one package. If you only update one package that might cause dependency issues so updating all packages simultaneously is the better option.